# gem groupdate issue with 2 timezones for same column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using the gems **ahoy** to track visits and **groupdate** to show daily stats.

To count daily visits I use this query in `Visit` model:

```
Visit.group_by_day(:started_at).order('started_at').count
```

It worked fine until last day 18, when my timezone changed from [BRT](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/brt) (-03:00) to [BRST](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/brst) (-02:00).

Now, the above query returns `0` visits count for each day after 18:

```
2.1.3 :026 > puts Visit.group_by_day(:started_at).order('started_at desc').limit(10).count.to_yaml
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, DATE_ADD(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_SUB(started_at, INTERVAL 0 HOUR), '+00:00', 'America/Sao_Paulo'), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), 'America/Sao_Paulo', '+00:00'), INTERVAL 0 HOUR) AS day FROM `visits` WHERE (started_at IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY DATE_ADD(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_SUB(started_at, INTERVAL 0 HOUR), '+00:00', 'America/Sao_Paulo'), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), 'America/Sao_Paulo', '+00:00'), INTERVAL 0 HOUR) ORDER BY started_at desc LIMIT 10
---
2015-10-14 03:00:00.000000000 Z: 158
2015-10-15 03:00:00.000000000 Z: 127
2015-10-16 03:00:00.000000000 Z: 101
2015-10-17 03:00:00.000000000 Z: 112
2015-10-18 03:00:00.000000000 Z: 111
2015-10-19 03:00:00.000000000 Z: 0
2015-10-20 03:00:00.000000000 Z: 0
2015-10-21 03:00:00.000000000 Z: 0
2015-10-22 03:00:00.000000000 Z: 0
```

But, if I select only the last 5 days (which are all in the BRST timezone), it works:

```
2.1.3 :027 > puts Visit.group_by_day(:started_at).order('started_at desc').limit(5).count.to_yaml
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, DATE_ADD(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_SUB(started_at, INTERVAL 0 HOUR), '+00:00', 'America/Sao_Paulo'), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), 'America/Sao_Paulo', '+00:00'), INTERVAL 0 HOUR) AS day FROM `visits` WHERE (started_at IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY DATE_ADD(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_SUB(started_at, INTERVAL 0 HOUR), '+00:00', 'America/Sao_Paulo'), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), 'America/Sao_Paulo', '+00:00'), INTERVAL 0 HOUR) ORDER BY started_at desc LIMIT 5
---
2015-10-19 02:00:00.000000000 Z: 85
2015-10-20 02:00:00.000000000 Z: 72
2015-10-21 02:00:00.000000000 Z: 84
2015-10-22 02:00:00.000000000 Z: 80
2015-10-23 02:00:00.000000000 Z: 21
```

**I did these 2 queries directly in mysql server, and both returns correct results.**

ie, when the query covers records with 2 different timezones, `groupdate`  can't count the records of the last one.

I want to make sure this is a groupdate gem bug. Or I missing something?

Comment: I take it you saw this?  https://github.com/ankane/groupdate#time-zones

Comment: Yes @Anthony, the timezone is configured correctly and everything works except when the `SELECT` retrieves records with two different timezones.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because you are doing zero-ing out the HH:mm:ss in between the two convert_tz's

Please update your SELECT for the 'day' variable:

1. remove the DATE_FORMAT
2. put the whole thing inside DATE() AS day

And then replace the GROUP BY value with just: day - or you can copy-paste the changes above into the group by

Comment: since this SQL is generated by groupdate gem, I can't change it. And, the problem isn't the SQL, cause I ran it on server and returned corrected results.